# Finite tor dimension in Quillen's paper

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Quillen gives the following projection formula his foundational paper on higher algebraic k-theory.  (For simplicity, I assume all schemes are noetherian.)

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper map of finite tor dimension. Assume $X, Y$ have ample line bundles. Then, for $x \in K_0 X, y \in K_q' Y$ we have $$ f_*(x \cdot f^* y) = f_* (x) \cdot y$$

Where he says $f_*: K_0 X \rightarrow K_0 Y$ is the map of SGA 6 2.12.2 (no expose given).

Question:

Notion of finite tor dimension

> > Quillen defines a morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to be "of finite tor dimension" if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is of finite tor dimension as a module over $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$.
> >
> > Suppose $X, Y$ are quasiprojective. Then, (ref: Fulton/MacPherson Categorical framework for the study of singular spaces) being a morphism of finite tor dimension is the same as being a perfect morphism in the sense of SGA 6.
> >
> > $\textbf{Question}$: I wasn't able to deduce if Quillen's notion of finite tor dimension is the same as being perfect in the sense of the stacks project (say if $X,Y$ have ample line bundles). Is this true?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. The question is still completely open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment: usually the pushforward on grothendieck groups is defined using higher direct images (or derived categories is you prefer), so that $f_*[E] = \sum (-1)^i [R^if_* E]$.

For this to be well defined you need properness to still land in coherent sheaves and only finitely many $R^i$ (which is true for essentially any morphism of everything).

On the other hand you can define $f^*$ on the level of Grothendieck groups again by using the derived inverse image (which is essentially computing Tors for $f^{-1}O_Y$), here you use finite tor dimension.

Comment: oh, and the projection formula then follows from the projection formula on the level of derived functors.

Comment: by the way, what do you mean by $K'_q$?

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. By $K'_q$ I mean Quillen's $K'$ theory, which agrees with $K-$theory on regular noetherian ... schemes.

Comment: where exactly in SGA are perfect _morphisms_ defined?

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand for me, but it is: Expose III, definition 4.1. It's on the top of page 256 of the scan available here: http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/pdf/sga6.pdf

Comment: haha,  I never said SGA 6, but I guess it was obvious from the link.

Comment: I would be surprised if the stacks project definition and the SGAVI definition would differ. Modulo this pseudo-coherence business this should be just having finite Tor-dimension.

Comment: and, also, since you're in the quasi-projective case, all these technical delicacies should evaporate (finite typeness is automatic and you can always resolve stuff by vector bundles).

Comment: Thanks. Also, by the way, do you know why the notion of perfectness is important? SGA devotes a lot of time to developing this notion in detail.

Comment: @abcd: whoops, I completely missed your comment way back. Sorry, and sorry again as my reply is: nope, I don't know. :(